# Creating separate process from web application request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

A client came to me with a request to have a web app that does a lot of processing in the backend (reads from a file, writes to a web service). My question is that since this "process" (when the user clicks 'Go') may  take hours, how do I make it so the processing continues after the user closes the web page? Please let me know if this does not make any sense and I can give more information. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @DmitryBoyko [editing a question](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/206335) just to bold certain parts? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create MS Windows Service for it.

You have provide for that Service some database table which client is going to use by your Website functionality.

Comment: Note that you typically cannot run a Windows Service in a shared hosting environment.  You need full access to the web server in order to install and manage the web service.  If you do not have such access, you can run the Windows Service on a separate machine that you do have access to.  In that event, the Web Server would have to send requests somehow to the other machine (e.g. via a web service call).  In an environment where you have heavy web traffic, it may be advisable to separate the Windows Service to a separate machine in any event.

Answer (score 1):

This is, basically, a "batch job" requirement, and that's how I suggest that you approach it.

The client would use the web-page, not to *perform* the work, but rather to manage the list of batch jobs that are performing the work .. scheduling them, starting or stopping them, viewing their status and current output, and so on.  *(Yup, just like they did it in the 1970's, but without "//FOOBAR JOB (123,456)" ... thank god.*

The user goes to the web-page and enters a request.  A back-end service process on the host (the batch job manager...) now starts the job, perhaps on one computer; perhaps on several at a time.  The user can, meanwhile, log off the web-site and do whatever he pleases.  Then, he can come back at any time, go back to whatever the job-monitoring web page may be, and see how things are going.  Stop the job, suspend/resume, what have you.

There are **lots** of batch-job monitoring tools out there already, for all sorts of environments, both free and commercial.  So, it's not like you have to *build* all this stuff; you merely have to *identify* what off-the-shelf package works best for you and for your client.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do this? Seems like it may be the route I need to take.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution will be to do the work in a windows service, and use your web app just to trigger the processing.

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 windows services in the same solution?

Comment: @IsaacLevin - Yes. You can have many different services in a solution. You can also install multiple services on one machine.

Comment: @Oded SO I would do something like in this example

http://www.fredmastro.com/post/Call-your-Web-Service-from-your-Web-Application.aspx

Comment: @IsaacLevin - No, that post is about controlling a windows service from a web application. That's not the same thing.